# selenium ide wildcard text matching - how

Tags: selenium-ide

I'm using selenium ide 3.17 with Firefox and trying to do a glob match on some text.
The entire webpage consists of
`<html><body>blah</body></html>`.

If I use command:assert text, target:css=body, value:blah, that passes.  But any wildcard such as glob:bla* or bla* fails, with something like
`Actual value "blah" did not match value "bla*"`

How might I use a wildcard or pattern match in the ide?

Answer (score 2):

```
store text|[your element]|StoredText  
execute script|return ${StoredText}.includes("bla")|x  
assert|x|true
```

could also use something like:

```
execute script|return ${StoredText}.startswith("bla")|x
```